# How do I keep Netbeans from printing line like this // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" UML Marker "> when printing code?

Tags: java, netbeans, printing, comments

I am trying to keep Netbeans from printing statement like this

```
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" UML Marker "> 
// #[regen=yes,id=DCE.B7E25FE1-C10B-ED91-77...
// </editor-fold>
```

without deleting them from the code.

Answer (score 1):

The editor-fold you posted is added when you generate code from a UML diagram created in Netbeans.  This UML markers are used for source code synchronization, between the UML and your Java class.  So one option would be not to use the UML source code generation features.

The UML code generation uses templates to generate the code.  You can manage the template being used under Tools -> Options -> UML -> Domain Templates.

These templates are customizable see the [NetBeans UML Custom Code Generation](http://www.netbeans.org/kb/docs/uml/codegen.html) documentation.